# Issues with Exoplayer for audio in notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications

have been using Exoplayer to manage audio in my notifications... but i found one issue that appears under certain conditions.

**Library version:  implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.2'**

- I send one notification with my emulator offline
- After that I cold boot my emulator
- I receive the notification (i can play manually or use playwhenready prop as true)
- The Audio Starts, after a few seconds

The problem is that after that i can't pause or close my notification and timer duration continue for hours i have to relaunch or close emulator to stop it.

My audio resource is 42s longer, but the notification keeps counting.

I tried stop it with a runnable using it when audio is ready inside Exoplayer listener, but it doesn't work.

***An Important detail is... if I open my app before audio start this issue doesn,t happen***

My code

```
if (audioUrl != null && !audioUrl.isEmpty()) {
 Handler mainHandler = new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
 Runnable myRunnable = () -> {
     ExoPlayer exoPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
     try {
       Log.d("EXO BUG", "GENERATE PLAYER NOTIFICATION");
       PlayerNotificationManager playerNotificationManager = new PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(
         getApplicationContext(),
         notificationId,
         "myChannelId").setMediaDescriptionAdapter(
            new DescriptionAdapter(title, body) {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent(Player player) {
               return pendingIntent;
            }
    }
  ).build();
  playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
  playerNotificationManager.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
  playerNotificationManager.setSmallIcon(notificationIcon);
  playerNotificationManager.setColor(notificationColor);
  playerNotificationManager.setUseNextAction(false);
  playerNotificationManager.setUsePreviousAction(false);
  com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new com.google.android.exoplayer2.audio.AudioAttributes.Builder()
    .setUsage(C.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
    .setContentType(C.AUDIO_CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
    .build();
  exoPlayer.setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes, false);
  if (isAutoplay && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
  }

  MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(Uri.parse(audioUrl));
  exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
  exoPlayer.prepare();
  exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(isAutoplay);
  exoPlayer.addListener(
    new Player.Listener() {
      @Override
      public void onPlaybackStateChanged(int state) {

        if (state == Player.STATE_READY && audioDuration != null && !audioDuration.isEmpty()) {
          if (isAutoplay) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                if (exoPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                  exoPlayer.stop();
                  exoPlayer.release();
                } else {
                  Log.d("EXO BUG", "NOT PLAYING");
                }
              }
            }, (Integer.parseInt(audioDuration) + 1) * 1000 L);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  );

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  Log.d("EXO BUG", "ERROR CATCH" + e.getMessage());
}
```

};

mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
}